# How to get a click on p-breadcrumb when click on home

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

```js
export class BreadcrumbDemo implements OnInit {

    private items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
            {label:'Categories'},
            {label:'Sports'},
            {label:'Football'},
            {label:'Countries'},
            {label:'Spain'},
            {label:'F.C. Barcelona'},
            {label:'Squad'},
            {label:'Lionel Messi', url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi'}
        ];
    }
}
```

In documentation `onItemClick` is provided but not explained how to use it

`<p-breadcrumb [model]="items"></p-breadcrumb>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when in your template;

```html
<p-breadcrumb [model]="items" (onItemClick)="itemClicked($event)"></p-breadcrumb>
```

in your component;

```js
export class BreadcrumbDemo implements OnInit {

    private items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
            {label:'Categories'},
            {label:'Sports'},
            {label:'Football'},
            {label:'Countries'},
            {label:'Spain'},
            {label:'F.C. Barcelona'},
            {label:'Squad'},
            {label:'Lionel Messi', url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi'}
        ];
    }

    itemClicked(event) {
       console.log(event.item);
    }
}
```

BTW, `onItemClick` is a new feature and it was added to PrimeNg on following releases:

- [8.2.0-LTS](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#-820-lts-2020-03-30)
- [7.2.1-LTS](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#-721-lts-2020-03-30)
- [9.0.1](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/commit/0357031fef1d27682d28a019676554ea7360f0e2)

I tested above code on 9.0.6 and it works. If you are using an older version than above releases it won't work.

**UPDATE:**
I checked out breadcrumb implementation and I noticed that there is a partially documented feature [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/eda4daddd9788edeabf8b022c7a0b434cc1a4ba4/src/app/components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.ts#L62). Apparently [MenuItem](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/eda4daddd9788edeabf8b022c7a0b434cc1a4ba4/src/app/components/common/menuitem.ts#L6) has [documented](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v6.1.6/#/menumodel) `command` property which gets executed when item is clicked. Since it wasn't documented in `p-breadcrumb` it was not easy to spot the feature.

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <p-breadcrumb [model]="items"></p-breadcrumb>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private items: MenuItem[] = [
    {
      label: "I am a clickable breadcrumb :)",
      command: e => {
        console.log(`"${e.item.label}" clicked!`);
      }
    },
    { label: "I am NOT a clickable breadcrumb :(" }
  ];
}
```

Here is a clickable breadcrumbs demo on primeng@6.1.7: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-kbxbb3

Comment: which version of primeng are you using?

Comment: i'm using version 6.1.7

Comment: I edited my answer, please see updated answer. `onItemClick` doesn't exists on version 6.1.7.

Comment: Oh! is there anyother way??